# C - Scanf not blocking for named pipe / FIFO

Tags: c

Usually when a program call a scanf it waits until something is available in stdin to read from it. I am currently making a fifo for input and another one for output that will be used by another process to write an read from a background proccess. But, the background process seem not to wait for any scanf in it, does anyone know why?

Here is the code:

Background:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
int main()
{
    int out, in, err;

    char *cFifo = "/tmp/out";
    char *cInFifo = "/tmp/in";

    mkfifo(cFifo, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
    mkfifo(cInFifo, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);

    out = open(cFifo, O_RDWR|O_TRUNC|O_NONBLOCK);
    in = open(cInFifo, O_RDWR|O_TRUNC|O_NONBLOCK);

    dup2(out, STDOUT_FILENO);
    dup2(out, STDERR_FILENO);
    dup2(in, STDIN_FILENO);


    scanf("%*c");

    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%*c");
        printf("Hello\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Foreground:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
int main()
{

    int out, in;
    size_t i = 0;

    char bufOut[1024];
    char *cFifo = "/tmp/out";
    char *cFifoIn = "/tmp/in";

    out = open(cFifo, O_RDONLY);

    in = open(cFifoIn, O_WRONLY);


    while(1)
    {
        i =0;
        while(!i)
        {
            i = read(out, bufOut, 1024);
        }

        if(i)
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, bufOut, i);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have already tried to force write on the new input fifo but the result is the same.

I already checked for errors, and everything return the expected values, no -1 or any other errors associated with each function

Comment: A good start might be to actually *check* for errors. Just about all functions you call will return a specific value on error, and then you check the `errno` variable to see what the error is. Read the [manual pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html) for all the functions.

Comment: Sorry I did not put it here, but I already checked for errors, and everything return the expected values, no -1 or any other errors associated with each function

Comment: Should not `if(i) write(STDOUT_FILENO, bufOut, i);` be `if(i >0) write(...` and use `ssize_t i = 0;`.  `ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);` returns a signed type.

Comment: @IndesejavelCoisa *"scanf not blocking"* (unexpectedly) and *"everything return the expected values"* are mutually exclusive. If `scanf` returns expected value, then it did manage to read what you asked.

Comment: What do you expect after `in = open(.... O_NONBLOCK)`?